# How do I integrate Facebook Messenger group conversations?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

We built a Facebook application for live agents to respond to Facebook Messenger messages to our clients' Pages.  When a Facebook user communicates directly to a Page, it works great.  However, one of our clients is using Facebook Business Marketplace, and messages from a Marketplace item were being received into our app until recently, when they stopped.  It looks like, all of a sudden, these messages are now being created as a *group conversation*, rather than between the user and the Page.  The group conversation has the user and the Page as the two members.

I followed the [Messenger Platform Getting Started](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/getting-started/) guide, but nowhere does it mention group conversations.  I see no mention of group conversations in the [Messenger Platform docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform) either.  I have found some very basic documentation about conversations in the [Pages docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/realtime), but I cannot figure out how to manually create a group conversation that includes a Page for development and testing purposes.

Currently our application has the following permissions:

- `manage_pages`
- `pages_messaging`
- `pages_messaging_subscriptions`
- `pages_show_list`

And our application has webhooks for the following events:

- `messages`
- `message_deliveries`
- `conversations`

Questions:

1. Is there documentation describing how to integrate group conversations?  What additional permissions are necessary?  What additional webhooks should I be listening to?
2. How can I create a group conversation that includes a Page as a member of the group to replicate this scenario?
3. Is there a logical reason why the Messenger Platform documentation and API does not cover group conversations?

Answer (score 0):

To integrate your pages chatbot into group conversations, you need to create a chat extension.

Chat extensions are at their root just an 'extension' of typical messenger bots.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/guides/chat-extensions/

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/guides/chat-extensions/#faq

Comment: Hmm, those docs make no mention of group conversations or that additional group webhooks will be delivered, just a lot of functionality we are not looking for. I see the example TaskMessengerBot, but I cannot figure out how to add it to a group conversation.  Can you please help show how to create such a group conversation with a similar existing bot?